# Is it possible to override action method for UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have one `UIButton`. I want to use the same `UIButton` to execute multiple actions. First I'm setting the action to a button programmatically.

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.function1), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Next, I want to discard that funtion and want to add other action.

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.function2), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Is it possible to override existing target for button?

Comment: It does not make sense using more than one addTarget to a button, the high level reasoning is : "button -> IBAction , then you develop your condition inside the action method..

Comment: leftBarButton.target = nil

if are looking for UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case you suggested wont override the previous action but add the second action to the button resulting in `ViewController.function1` and `ViewController.function2` being called.

You need to remove the previous action from target before adding new one by using

`button1.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.function1), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)`

Or remove all the previous actions before adding the new one

`button1.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the previous action from target before adding new one else it will cause both the actions to trigger

```
button1.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.function1), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommande you to create a wrapper function. Because adding / removing target dynamically may leads to dead lock.

So you probably must create a function which will be always called, and do your stuff in :

```
@IBOutlet func myWrapper(sender : AnyObject?) {

 if (conditionA) {
  // do stuff A 
 } else {
  // do stuff B
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide case of deadlock you are talking about, please?

Comment: This is the most sensible answer and compliant with Apple framework.

Comment: No I can't because I don't know your code, what I mean is you may be in a state where you remove all target, or add 2 target. It is really hard to secure. having an if-else statement is the more secure way ( and debuggable way ) to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

As you added the target, you can remove it using [removeTarget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:) method on your button :

```
func removeTarget(_ target: AnyObject?,
       action action: Selector,
 forControlEvents controlEvents: UIControlEvents)
```

**EDIT** : See @Rohit KP's answer for example of usage. However you might want to consider using something else that '.AllEvents" depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Parent code:

```
@IBAction open func valueChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    (do something)
}
```

Child code:

```
override open func valueChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    super.valueChanged(sender)
    changeColorsOnState()
}
```